# Getting last messages by receivers in SMS app - SQL request

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm making a small web app to send SMS. I've got to show to users their last sent SMS (like SMS app in Android, iOS...)

My three tables :

```
---------   -----------   -----------
| users |   |  sms    |   | indexes |
---------   -----------   -----------
   id           id            id
   ..         user_id       user_id
              receiver      phone_n
             created_at      name
```

I've already made a SQL request to get last sent SMS grouped by name/phone_numbers of Indexes table :

```
SELECT S.receiver, S.message, I.name, temp.last_sent, I.id
FROM sms S
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT receiver, user_id, MAX(created_at) AS last_sent
        FROM sms
        WHERE user_id = ?
        GROUP BY receiver, user_id
    ) temp
ON S.receiver = temp.receiver
AND S.user_id = temp.user_id
AND S.created_at = temp.last_sent
LEFT OUTER JOIN indexes I ON S.receiver = I.phone_number WHERE I.user_id = ? 
ORDER BY temp.last_sent DESC
```

This SQL request works. I'm getting by receiver names the last SMS an user send to it.
But I'm getting only SMS where receiver are present in Indexes table.
All the SMS sent to receivers who have not their phone numbers saved in this database are not shown.

I know I made a mistake with my `LEFT OUTER JOIN indexes`. But

So how can I get last SMS sent by receivers, ordered by last_sent, with phone numbers saved or not in Indexes ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the WHERE clause into the ON clause for the LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT S.receiver, S.message, I.name, temp.last_sent, I.id
FROM sms S
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT receiver, user_id, MAX(created_at) AS last_sent
        FROM sms
        WHERE user_id = ?
        GROUP BY receiver, user_id
    ) temp
ON S.receiver = temp.receiver
AND S.user_id = temp.user_id
AND S.created_at = temp.last_sent
LEFT OUTER JOIN indexes I ON S.receiver = I.phone_number 
AND I.user_id = ? 
ORDER BY temp.last_sent DESC
```